# locating text in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

there's an html code on a web page that I'm trying to automate, and one of the line goes something like this:

```
<"option value = "1">ABC<"/option>"
```

I am wondering if there are anyways to locate this without using the value, but locating it through text ABC.  I have ABC stored under a variable, and I'm planning to pass that variable in.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dropdown_menu"))
select.select_by_visible_text(abc_variable)
```

Comment: Keeps saying that it can't "locate element with visible text:ABC"

Answer (score 0):

Try by xpath..`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()='ABC']")`

Comment: but I have a variable that I stored ABC in, and I'm trying to pass in the variable.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[text()='" + your_var + "']")` ??